# How to filter between two dates with the Date Filter in API Platform

Tags: api, symfony4, api-platform.com

im using API Platform together with Symfony 4 and im trying to use the date filter as described here: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/

when i use the filter like this ....something?_page=1&lieferdat[after]=2018-12-01&lieferdat[before]=2018-12-30

the hydra response shows that the brackets are url encoded and i think its not working properly as i get all results instead of the filtered ones.
In my Entity i added the DateFilter as any other filter which seems to be correct.

Hydra Response:
 "something?lieferdat%5Bafter%5D=2018-12-01&lieferdat%5Bbefore%5D=2018-12-30&_page=1"

Can anybody explain if i can use brackets in my requests or better: 
Can anybody provide a working Date Filter implementation for Api Platform which demonstrates how to filter between two dates?

Thanks in advice,
Best regards

Answer (score 5):

Ok im answering my own question..
The answer to my question: Are those url encoded brackets recognized by symfony api platform? the answer is: YES

After doing some trial and error with Postman, i got it working.

When i order my query reversed:

instead

```
something?lieferdat[after]=2019-03-01&lieferdat[before]=2019-03-31
```

i reversed it to this

```
something?lieferdat[before]=2019-03-31&lieferdat[after]=2019-03-01
```

which worked!

The only thing is, that sometimes if i specify a month, i sometimes get 1-2 values from the month before which is not what i wanted and is confusing me.
I tried to use

```
?lieferdat[strictly_before]=2019-03-31&lieferdat[strictly_after]=2019-03-01
```

but that didn't bring the effect.

Edit2: Ok the answer is simple, in my entity i defined the search filter but i didn't define a property on which this filter works, so it works on all date properties in that entity

Any help still appreciated :)

Comment: The syntax for the date filter is `?property[<after|before|strictly_after|strictly_before>]=value`. The value can take any date format supported by the `\DateTime` constructor. The after and before filters will filter including the value whereas `strictly_after` and `strictly_before` will filter excluding the value.

Long story short; your solutions works correctly, right?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if this solution may help but this is what I normally do... First, the URL of your request should be encoded like this:

```
http://example.com/api/some-endpoint?availableDate.date%5Bstrictly_before%5D=2020-01-02&availableDate.date%5Bstrictly_after%5D=2020-02-04&page=1
```

and your entity should be annotated like this:

```
@ApiFilter(
  DateFilter::class,
  properties={
       "availableDate"
  }
```

)

also notice that you can filter properties from embedded objects like this:

```
 @ApiFilter(
  DateFilter::class,
  properties={
       "exampleProperty.embeddedProperty"
  }
```

)

where "exampleProperty" is the field inside the entity where you are going to filter and "embeddedProperty" is the name of the field in the other entity (the embedded one)

and this is an example how I created the URL in JavaScript for make the AJAX request:

```
export const setAvailableDateURLFilters = ( pag = null, before = null, strictlyBefore = null,after = null, strictlyAfter = null) =>{
let url = "/api/available-dates?";

if(before)
    url === "/api/available-dates?" ? (url += "date%5Bbefore%5D=" + before) : (url += "&date%5Bbefore%5D=" + before);
if(strictlyBefore)
    url === "/api/available-dates?" ? (url += "date%5Bstrictly_before%5D=" + strictlyBefore) : (url += "&date%5Bstrictly_before%5D=" + strictlyBefore);
if(after)
    url === "/api/available-dates?" ? (url += "date%5Bafter%5D=" + after) : (url += "&date%5Bafter%5D=" + after);
if(strictlyAfter)
    url === "/api/available-dates?" ? (url += "date%5Bstrictly_after%5D=" + strictlyAfter) : (url += "&date%5Bstrictly_after%5D=" + strictlyAfter);
if(pag)
    url === "/api/available-dates?" ? ( url += 'page=' + pag) : (url += '&page=' + pag);

return url;
```

}

your answer was right! I'm just adding some tips and info! Hope this help someone... Cheers!